# Return first value after if statement is true

Tags: xml, xquery

I have following xml:

```
<test>
    <TestStruktur>
        <TestReference>ID_text_random_uuid</TestReference>
        <TestReference>ID_test_random_uuid</TestReference>
        <Name>Some name</Name>
    </TestStruktur>
    <TestStruktur>
        <TestReference>ID_test_random_uuid</TestReference>
        <TestReference>ID_text_random_uuid</TestReference>
        <Name>Some name</Name>
    </TestStruktur>
</test>
```

I need to search for TestReference elements and check if values contain `test` string and then return value from the `<Name>` element. I've created xquery that does it but it returns two values because the statement is true for two nodes.
Of course this is only a sample xml. I can have a lot of `TestStruktur` nodes and even more `TestReference` nodes

Here's my xquery:

```
declare function local:test($doc as node()) as xs:string {
    for $test2 in $doc//test/TestStruktur
        for $test in $test2/TestReference
        return
            if(contains($test, 'test')) then 
                data($test2/Name)
            else ()
};

for $doc in collection('Testing')
return local:test($doc)
```

Is there any way to, for example, break loop when if statement is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the returned results to the first node:

```
(for $test2 in $doc//test/TestStruktur
 for $test in $test2/TestReference
 where contains($test, 'test')
 return data($test2/Name)
)[position() = 1]
```

This solution may look expensive at first glance, but many XQuery implementation stop looping as soon as the first result has been found.

Comment: ＋1, but `[position() = 1]` can be shortened to `[1]`

Comment: Absolutely true. I chose the verbose syntax, because it can more easily be adjusted to range tests.

Answer (score 1):

You just filter for the first result:

```
declare function local:test($doc as node()) as xs:string {
  (
    for $test2 in $doc//test/TestStruktur
        for $test in $test2/TestReference
        return
            if(contains($test, 'test')) then 
                data($test2/Name)
            else ()
  )[1]
};
```

The predicate might be a case for a quantifier:

```
declare function local:test($doc as node()) as xs:string
{
  (
    for $test2 in $doc//test/TestStruktur
    where some $test in $test2/TestReference satisfies contains($test, 'test')
    return $test2/Name
  )
  [1]
};
```

But it could as well be done in a single path expression:

```
declare function local:test($doc as node()) as xs:string
{
  ($doc//test/TestStruktur[TestReference[contains(., 'test')]]/Name)[1]
};
```

All of the above are equivalent. Note that the result type might better be `xs:string?`, to provide for the case of no `'test'` being found.